# Does cakephp 3 store cache of database instances?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to get instance of database table in cakePHP 3. 
Simple code:

```
$r = TableRegistry::get('envelope')
    ->find()
    ->where(['enID'=>$id])
    ->first();
```

It works. But when I add new column in `'envelope'` table, new column is not appear in `$r`.
Seems like a cache? Or what I am doing wrong?

don't know why but it works only when I write all columns names, like here:

```
$r = TableRegistry::get('envelope')
    ->find()
    ->select(array('enID','title_web','description'))
    ->where(['enID'=>$id])
    ->first();
```

Comment: I don't know why but it works only when I write all columns names, like here: $r = TableRegistry::get('envelope')->find()->select(array('enID','title_web','description'))->where(['enID'=>$id])->first();

Answer (score 1):

yes, Model schema is cached in cakephp as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-engines) in the cookbook

You can set your cache duration to whatever you want, so if you add a column ad you wait the time set in the cache engine you should see it added to the query.

You can find the cache engine definition inn config/app.php

If after the expiration time the table schema is not updated you may have other issues

If you have `debug` set to `true` the cache duration is usually set to a shorter time (i.e. 2 minutes)

Also if you enable debugKit (as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html)) it will show you a cache panel when you can see all the active cache engines and you can reset the `_cake_model_` cache whenever you want

Comment: One can also easily clear the cache afterwards from the command line:                 `$ bin/cake cache clear _cake_model_`.

Comment: thanks you really helped me! Just switched cake to debug mode and everything is working!